# Non Zero Exit Code in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone please specify where is my error.
As soon as i posted this on codechef it throws NZEC error.
Anyone has any idea why there is a Non Zero Exit Code error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class AlternatingSubarrayPrefix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            array[k] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int count = 0;
        int[] result = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1 ; j++) {
            if(array[j] < 0 && array[j+1] > 0 || array[j] > 0 && array[j+1] < 0)
                result[j] = ++count;
            else {
                count = 1;
                result[j] = count;

            }   
        }
        if(array[n-1] < 0 && array[n-2] > 0 || array[n-1] > 0 && array[n-2] < 0)
            result[n-1] = ++count;
        else {
            count = 1;
            result[n-1] = count;
        }   
        for(int j = n-1; j >=0; j--) 
            System.out.print(result[j] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `n` guaranteed to be at least 2?

Comment: There are potential input validation errors (enter a string instead of int), as well as index out of bounds exceptions possible. If you have the stack trace for the exception, that would be useful to post as part of your question.